Brightness all the way down and the brightness option doesn't work after suspending in debian
I am new to linux and this is my first time encountering this issue. I just installed debian 12 and it was working fine till today. I just opened my laptop and the moment it started after being suspended, i saw that the screen brightness was all the way down. I could barely read it and tried turning the brightness up by function keys and the brightness option in the menu on the screen. It didn't work.
